# Android PHP JSON parsing giving 404 error but fetching data

Tags: php, android, json, http-status-code-404

I have a problem which is quite confusing for me. So, I am parsing data from mysql to my android device. The thing is from the server end, I am getting a 404 error but data is getting fetched successfully and populated in my listview. This is quite disadvantageous as I have to bypass the code

```
StatusLine responseStatus = response.getStatusLine();
  if (responseStatus.getStatusCode() != 200) {}
```

Which is responsible for detecting an actual server error. The link I call from the android end to fetch the json data is `http://applink.skibzy.com/1/index.php?action=fetchdata` and when I call the url from a browser, the json encoded data is displayed and a http status code 404 is registered on the server end. Kindly help me solve this awkward yet confusing issue. The respective files involved are FetchBlogPostData.java, MainActivity.java and index.php

**index.php**

```
<?php
require('db.php');
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action == 'fetchdata') {
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');
if (mysql_num_rows($query) >= '1') {
    $a = array();
    while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $post = array();
        $post["title"] = $b['post_title'];
        //$post["who"] = DB_USER;
        array_push($a, $post);  
    }
    echo json_encode($a);
}
}
?>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener {

Constants constant;
Utils utils;

private ActionBarActivity action;
private ProgressBar dialog;
public TextView post_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    constant = new Constants();
    utils = new Utils(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dialog = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    initView();
}

private void initView() {
// show progress dialog
    dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = "http://applink.skibzy.com/1/index.php?action=fetchdata";
    FetchBlogPostData task = new FetchBlogPostData(this);
    task.execute(url);
    //getListView().setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<BlogPostValue> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null) dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    post_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postID);
    // create new adapter
    BlogPostAdapter adapter = new BlogPostAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog
    if(dialog != null) dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("error", msg);
    dataBundle.putString(constant.PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY, constant.THE_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ErrorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

**FetchBlogPostData.java**

```
public class FetchBlogPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private final FetchDataListener listener;
private String msg;
public FetchBlogPostData(FetchDataListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if(params == null) return null;
        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity == null) {
                msg = "Try Again";
                return null;
            }

            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            msg = "No Internet Connection";
        }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {
    if (sJson == null) {
        if (listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
        return;
    }
    try {
        // convert json string to json array
        JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);
        // create apps list
        List<BlogPostValue> apps = new ArrayList<BlogPostValue>();
        for (int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
            BlogPostValue app = new BlogPostValue();
            app.setID(json.getString("id"));
            app.setTitle(json.getString("title"));
            app.setExerpt(json.getString("exerpt"));
            app.setCreated(json.getString("created"));
            app.setTotalComments(json.getString("comments"));
            app.setCommentStatus(json.getString("comment_status"));
            app.setIcon(json.getString("thumbnail"));
            // add the app to apps list
            apps.add(app);
        }
        //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
        if (listener != null) listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        msg = "Try Again";
        if (listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
    }
}

/**
 * This function will convert response stream into json string
 * @param is respons string
 * @return json string
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: What should 'path_to_my_file' be, and can you post your complete http request method?

Comment: @mjp66 The full link is `http://applink.skibzy.com/1/index.php?action=fetchdata`. I have also edited the question to reflect the same.

Comment: Thanks. And could you post some additional source code (your http get/post/response methods)?

Comment: @mjp66, check the edit, I have added the files in the question.

Comment: I recreated a project using your code and calling your url.... getting the same results as you: a 404 but the json string comes along in the response. Calling this via browser also returns the json string but the response code is also 404. My guess is you're going to have to look at your server and check how it handles page-not-found errors. BTW are you sure the url you gave is correct?

Comment: Yes,  the link is okay. What I do not understand is why a page not found error is called and at the same time the data is fetched successfully...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94118/discussion-between-mjp66-and-biko).